# find the complexity for loop

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

what is the time complexity T(n) of the following potion of the code? for simplicity you may assume that n is power of 2. that is n=2^k . for some positive integer k.

```
for(i=1;;I<=n;i++)
  for(j=n/2;j<n;j++)
      print x;
```

choose the correct answer:

1. T(n)=n+1
2. T(n)=n^2+2n
3. T(n)=n
4. T(n)=n^3
5. T(n)=n(n/2 +1)

Comment: What do *you* think it is? And why?

Comment: Looks very homework-ey...

Comment: I thing its T(n)=n+1 because first loop T(n) =n and since in second loop we are dividing  by two one n will be cancel.. I am not sure!

Answer (score 1):

So lets write some iterations:

```
i           j
1           0       to n-1
2           1       to n-1
3           1       to n-1
4           2       to n-1
5           2       to n-1
.
.
.
n-2         (n-2)/2 to n-1  
n-1         (n-2)/2 to n-1  
n           n/2     to n-1
```

Now lets remember `1st` and `nth` and calculate sum of ranges(`end - start + 1`) from `i = 2` till `i = n-1`.

```
S = (n-1 - 1 + 1) + (n-1 - 1 + 1) + (n-1 - 2 + 1) + (n-1 - 2 + 1) + ...  + (n-1 - (n-2)/2 + 1) + (n-1 - (n-2)/2 + 1)
```

...

```
S = (n - 1) + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + (n - 2) + ...  + (n - (n-2)/2) + (n - (n-2)/2)
```

...

```
S = 2*(n - 1) + 2*(n - 2) + ... + 2*(n - (n - 2)/2)
```

...

```
S = 2*((n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + (n - (n - 2)/2))
```

...

```
S = 2*(n*(n-2)/2 - (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 2)/2 ))
```

...

Last is arithmetic progression which is calculated by formula:

```
N*(A1 + A2)/2
```

where:

```
N = (n - 2)/2,      A1 = 1,      A2 = (n - 2)/2
```

So we end up with:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 2)/2 =  n*(n - 2)/8
```

...

```
S = n^2 - 2*n - 2*(n*(n - 2)/8)
```

...

```
S = n^2 - 2*n - n*(n - 2)/4
```

Now lets add 2 values that we remembered:

```
S = n + n/2 + n^2 - 2*n - n*(n - 2)/4
```

...

```
S = (4*n + 2*n + 4*n^2 - 8*n)/4 - n*(n - 2)/4
```

...

```
S = (4*n + 2*n + 4*n^2 - 8*n - n^2 + 2*n)/4
```

...

```
S = (3/4)*n^2
```

I am getting none of the above. I have checked and rechecked but can not find the error.